# Orthogonal and orthonormal basis in the vector space of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal

Find an orthogonal basis with integer coefficients in the vector space of polynomials $f(t)$ of degree at most $2$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with inner product $\langle f, g\rangle=\int_0^1f(t)g(t)\, dt$.

In addition, find an orthonormal basis for the above space.

$$$$

I have done the following:

Let $S=\{1,x,x^2\}$.

We normalize the first vector of the basis.

$v_1=1$

$\langle v_1, v_1\rangle=\langle 1, 1\rangle=1$

$\tilde{v}_1=\frac{v_1}{\|v_1\|}=1$

$w_2:=v_2-\langle v_2,v_1\rangle v_1=x-\langle x,1\rangle 1=x-\frac{1}{2}$

$v_2=\frac{w_2}{\|w_2\|}=2\sqrt{3}\left (x-\frac{1}{2}\right )$

$w_3:=v_3-\langle v_3,v_1\rangle v_1-\langle v_3,v_2\rangle v_2=x^2-\langle x^2,1\rangle 1-\langle x^2,2\sqrt{3}x-\sqrt{3}\rangle \left (2\sqrt{3}x-\sqrt{3}\right )=\ldots =x^2-x+\frac{1}{6}$

$v_3=\frac{w_3}{\|w_3\|}=6\sqrt{5}\left (x^2-x+\frac{1}{6}\right )$

Therefore an orthonormal basis is $$\left \{1 \ , \ 2\sqrt{3}x-\sqrt{3} \ , \  6\sqrt{5}\left (x^2-x+\frac{1}{6}\right )\right \}$$ that is also orthogonal.

Is everything correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything is well and good. You followed the Gram-Schmidt process and got a right result. Well done!

Edit: for the orthogonal part. It remains to get integer coefficients (multiply by the pertinent square roots to do away with them) and to re-normalise to get norm-one vectors.

Comment: By "missed one part of the question" do you mean that I didn't find an orthogonal basis separatetly from finding an orthonormal one? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Asked about orthogonality, not orthonormality. In all honesty, I missed the 'orthonormal' bit since I was doing the corresponding integrals by hand to check that it was, in effect, orthogonal.

Comment: @MaryStar There are two parts. One is to find an orthogonal set with integer coefficients and the other is to find an orthonorml basis. Did you do the first part?

Comment: $\{1,2x-1,6x^{2}-6x+1\}$ is an orthogonal set with integer coefficients.

Comment: The second part, about the orthonormal basis, is correct, isn't it? So, we cannot just say that the orthonormal basis is also orthogonal, we have to find an other one? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Your orthnormal set does not have integer coefficients.

Comment: So, the orthonormal part is correct and for the orthogonal part we have to multiply the orthonormal basis appropriately to get integer coefficients. have I understood that correct? @SamSkywalker

Comment: The **orthogonal** part is about to be correct: you need to multiply the second vector by $\sqrt 3$ and the third vector by $\sqrt 5$ in order to get an orthogonal basis **with integer coefficients**. In order to get an **orthonormal** basis, you need to multiply each vector by the inverse of its modulus.